# Seeking Egyptian Arabic dictionary with sort of most common single words top down style

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources, vocabulary, arabic, dictionary

I am looking for a website which has an app for the most common single Egyptian Arabic words, with the ability to sort words from most common to least common, preferably with romanization included in the list. I myself found two sites, https://www.101languages.net/arabic/most-common-arabic-words/ and  https://arabic.desert-sky.net/. The second one is close, but lacks sorting, and I found some inconsistencies in that the translations of some words and the words themselves seem to be unrelated to each other. The first one is acceptable, but does not seem to have romanization available.

Comment: https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/q/899/195 seems relevant.

Answer (score 2):

The [Swadesh List for Egyptian Arabic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Egyptian_Arabic_Swadesh_list) is probably too short since it contains only 207 words, but other resources for *Egyptian* Arabic are heard to find. There are a few resources for Arabic in general that may be useful:

- *A Frequency Dictionary of Arabic* by Tim Buckwalter and Dilworth Parkinson ([Routledge, 2011](https://www.routledge.com/A-Frequency-Dictionary-of-Arabic-Core-Vocabulary-for-Learners-1st-Edition/Buckwalter-Parkinson/p/book/9780415444347), 580 pages). This book provides "a list of the 5,000 most frequently used words in Modern Standard Arabic (MSA) as well as several of the most widely spoken Arabic dialects." In addition to the book version, there is also a CD-ROM version.
- *Häufigkeitswörterbuch der modernen arabischen Zeitungssprache / Frequency dictionary of modern newspaper Arabic* by Wolf-Dietrich Fromm (Verlag Enzyklopädie, 1982). This book is now out of print, but you can check its availability in a library near you through [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/haufigkeitsworterbuch-der-modernen-arabischen-zeitungssprache-ein-mindestwortschatz-arabisch-deutsch-englisch-a-skeleton-vocabulary-arabic-german-english-frequency-dictionary-of-modern-newspaper-arabic/oclc/469549168/editions?referer=di&editionsView=true).

Gabriel Wyner, author of the book *Fluent Forever*, published a list of the 625 most frequently used words in English (see the blog post [The Most Awesome Word List You Have Ever Seen](https://blog.fluent-forever.com/base-vocabulary-list/)), which you might want to translate into Egyptian Arabic. The result may not be the same as creating an Egyptian Arabic frequency list from scratch, but it's a decent starting point.

(The 101Languages website has a list of [1,000 Most Common Arabic Words](https://www.101languages.net/arabic/most-common-arabic-words/), which can be downloaded in Excel format, which allows easy sorting etcetera. Unfortunately, this is not focused on Egyptian Arabic either, and you already know about that list.)

Answer (score 1):

The [Swadesh List](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Egyptian_Arabic_Swadesh_list), available on Wiktionary, has many of the most common words. Another advantage is that you can compare any word with those of MSA and other Arabic dialects (or nearly any language, for that matter).

There's not a great frequency-sorted list specific to Egyptian that I'm aware of, but Lughatuna has a good English-Egyptian dictionary that you could use to translate an English frequency list. Word (or lemma) frequency tends to be extremely correlated between languages, and an advantage to this approach is that you would learn a thing or two about word ambiguities and the subtleties of translation.